# Elegant way of enabling specific Columns in a dynamic WPF UniformGrid to be resizable

Tags: wpf, dynamic, itemscontrol, uniformgrid

like the title says: Is there an elegant way of enabling specific columns in a dynamic UniformGrid to be resizable?

*The details*:

I have a ItemsControl and set the ItemsPanelTemplate to be of type UniformGrid. The ItemTemplate is set to a Custom Control that renders the column content.

Here is the xaml excerpt:

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="PART_Dimensions" 
            Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>

        <UniformGrid Columns="{Binding 
            Path=ItemsSource.Count, 
            RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
            AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" 
                        IsItemsHost="True"/>

    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>

            <local:Dimension 
                PropertyA="{Binding SourceA}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding SourceB}" />

    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Now, what i'm trying to achieve is to make it possible, that specific columns are resizable, giving them a static width while still allowing the other columns to be sized uniformly in width.

Has anyone some direction to point me to? I was hoping to avoiding too specific custom implementations of the Rendering of the UniformGrid, is there a smart and easy way doing this?

thanks in advance
with regards
Ole

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to keep a few columns with static width and let others have a dynamic width, I would say `UniformGrid` is not the right `Panel` to go with.

Why don't you go with a `StackPanel` with `Horizontal Orientation`? From you code, I see you only need one row.

If that does not work for you, go with `Grid`. You will need to write some code but that will give you the best results. You can use `GridSplitter` to make `Grid` columns resizable.

Comment: Thanks decyclone. I tried a StackPanel in the first place, but i had problems in automatically sizing the contents of the "columns" to the biggest possible width. At first a Grid seems like a good choice, but is it possible to let it do the templating that an ItemsControl allows you to do?

Comment: Of course it is possible. This article (http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/11/using-a-grid-as-the-panel-for-an-itemscontrol/) shows you how to do that.

Comment: In fact each item to be displayed is a ItemsControl itself with custom arrangement logic, so the items (ItemsControl within the ItemsControl) have to be arranged horizontically. And yes, it is only one row, since the items increment in the column direction. Problem with the stackpanel is, that is does not size its children automatically as far as i know. The link to scottlogic is interesting but does only give a bit insight on how to customize the grid. I have to dig into this. thanks though